# Converting a string of 0s and 1s into a byte array

Tags: c#, textbox, byte, bit

I want to write the following sequence of bits in a textbox, like this:

> 000101100000000100000001000000010000000000100111001100010010000000110000001011100011000000110000001100000011000000100000001100110011100100101110001101110011010100100000001100000010111000110000001110000010000000110000001011100011000000110000001000000011000000101110001100000011000000110000001100000000010111010111

But every each 8 bits corresponds to a byte, so I want to store them in a `byte[]` array. Of course, if I read them like this:

```
byte[] byteBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageTextBox.Text);
```

Each `0` or `1` turns into a whole byte, which is not what I want.

Is there any straightforward solution, like some existing method, or I have to develop my own?

Comment: What language are you using?  Looks like C# to me, but you might want to add the appropriate tag to your post just to make it clear.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it. It's C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written the following code on the go without any compiler so please apologize syntax errors - also you have to take care of reaching the end of the text string on your own, its not included. I think the below method does what you want to do ..

```
private bytes[] extractBytes (string text) {

    byte[] bytes = new byte[100];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    string currentByte = "";

    while (i <= text.Length) {

         currentByte += text.Substring(i, 1);

         i++;

         if (i % 8 == 0) {

             j++;

             bytes[j] = convertToDecimal(currentByte);
             currentByte = "";
         }
    )

    return bytes;
}
```

If you want to save the decimal value that is represented by the binary value you have extracted from your string you can use this conversion method:

```
private byte convertToDecimal (string binary) {

    int i = 0;
    int byte = 0;

    while (i < s.Length) {

        if (s.Substring(s.Length - 1 - i, 1).Equals("1")) {

            sum += (byte)Math.Pow(2, i);
        }

        i++;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the next error:

`Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte from string`

At the line: `bytes[j] = Byte.Parse(currentByte);`

While trying to parse `00110001`. I think it's due to the system don't understand that the string represents a binary value, but I don't know how to get it right

Comment: ok I see .. what is it that you want to have extracted from the long string? strings like "11001001" or the number representation of it like e.g. 34 ?

Comment: @Ger I have added a method that lets you convert string representing a binary number into a decimal byte. See my adapted and updated post above.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry for the delay answering

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Convert.ToByte()` and do something like:

```
string str = messageTextBox.Text;
byte[] byteBuffer = Enumerable.Range(0, str / 8).
                        Select(pos => Convert.ToByte(
                        str.Substring(pos * 8, 8),
                        2)).ToArray();
```