# C# - Convert string of zeros and ones to a byte array or similar

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I am getting a string of zeros and ones from a client API request. They are of a set length (28, in this case) and I want to convert them to a `byte[]` or something similar, with the goal of storing these in SQL via EF Core and later using bitwise operators to compare them.

I can't seem to wrap my head around this one. I'm seeing a lot of posts/questions about converting characters to byte arrays, or byte arrays to strings, neither of which is what I need.

I need a `"00111000010101010"` to become a literal binary `00111000010101010` I can use a `^` on.

Leading zeros would be fine if necessary, I think the length might be forced to be a multiple of 8?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a string of 0s and 1s into a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090317/converting-a-string-of-0s-and-1s-into-a-byte-array)

Comment: I think this covers the BitWise operation part of the question https://stackoverflow.com/a/38042609/495455 it's not the best news. I'd be inclined to search GitHub for a library that bridges this gap.

Comment: Converting to an integer is just `int("01011101",2)`, but it's often easier to do those comparisons as characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can binary string convert to an integer easily with this:

```
string source = "00111000010101010";
int number = Convert.ToInt32(source, 2); // The `2` is "base 2"
```

That gives: `28842`.

Then you can go one step further an convert to a byte array, if needed.

```
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(number);
```

Comment: I think I can just run the bitwise directly against the resulting ints, right?

Comment: @RandyHall - Yes, you can. You specifically asked about a `byte[]` so I gave you that too.